# Why would cron be "skipping" scheduled jobs

Tags: linux

I have 3 tasks sheduled to crontab on my server,
but my second job doesn't run automatically

```
\# m h  dom mon dow   command
*/5 * * * * ~/dbCron.sh
00 09 * * * ~/dbCron_daily_backup.sh           <--------- this is skipping
55 23 * * * ~/backup_logs.sh && ~/clear_logs.sh
```

so what could be the solution that would run the tasks at proper time without fail.

Comment: Is the job runnning from your command prompt when you enter `~/dbCron_daily_backup.sh`? And a bunch of helpful hints on http://serverfault.com/questions/449651/why-is-my-crontab-not-working-and-how-can-i-troubleshoot-it

Comment: Try replacing your script with a simple command and make sure you capture error output : `date > ~/cron.log 2>~/cron.log`. Does that run correctly? If so, your problem is in your script.

Comment: Like someone else said, you can't use relative name `~/` in your path in the crontab file, you  must use absolute paths like: `/home/me/jobs/myjob.sh`. the same thing applies to all programs called inside myjob.sh, they must all use absolute paths because when the cron job runs, it has no PATH variable, or at least the PATH variable is not the same as your own login shell. Also remember to edit your LOCAL crontab using `crontab -e` while logged in as a normal user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script is running, and failing.  Please use absolute paths to your script (e.g. "/home/yourid/bin/dbCron_daily_backup.sh"), and edit/revise your script to use absolute paths for all commands.  Likely you have an environment issue, which could be solved by sourcing appropriate environment configuration at the top of your script.

Do yourself a favor and create a logging directory, so you can observe/monitor your cronjob behavior,

```
mkdir /home/yourid/log/
```

Here is an idiom which you can use to log the crontab behavior (assuming you have a place to log your work); this will capture stdout and stderr,

```
#periodic db work,
*/5 * * * * (cd /home/yourid/; bin/dbCron.sh) 2>&1 >> /home/yourid/log/dbcron.log
#db daily backup
00 09 * * * (cd /home/yourid; bin/dbCron_daily_backup.sh) 2>&1 >> /home/yourid/log/dbdailybackup.log
#db nightly cleanup
55 23 * * * (cd /home/yourid/; bin/backup_logs.sh && bin/clear_logs.sh) 2>&1 >> /home/yourid/log/dbnightlycleanup.log

#log system health,
0 * * * * (cd /opt/myapp/;util/DiskCheck.pl) 2>&1 >> /home/yourid/log/health.log
```

You might want to print out messages at the start and end of your scripts with the date/time, so that you can note progress, for example,

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "begin $0 " `/bin/date +%y%m%d%H%M%S`
echo do stuff
echo "done $0 " `/bin/date +%y%m%d%H%M%S`
```

Comment: well, it surely provide me a opportunity to debug/ know errors occurred, and it did helps, thank you. _though i had asked alternative to cronjob as I thought it was unreliable, this answer really helped me._

Comment: cron is not unreliable, just often misunderstood.  I have found the above insight helpful.  My biggest problem with cron has been tasks which depend upon one another, though some feel the 'catchup' issues with cron are a problem.

Comment: Also I would like to add here that, though the backup script runs well in shell environment, the cronjob uses its own environment, which infact gets overflowed in case of large verbose ( tar cvaf ... ... ), which will result in incomplete backup. so turnoff verbosity alongside generating logs of cron